# How to test Devise user was created with proper password with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

Is there a way to test that a Devise user was created with the correct password in RSpec?

I have a feature spec for creating a user, and have tried testing that `created_user.encrypted_password eq User.new(password: same_as_created_user).encrypted_password` but the passwords generated do not match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the devise `valid_password?` method (more info [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable))

In your spec:

`expect(user.valid_password?('password')).to be_truthy`